# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to 1}{\left(\frac{(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^{2n})}{({(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^n)})^2}\right)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to 1}{\left(\frac{(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^{2n})}{({(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^n)})^2}\right)}$$ 
i am a 12th class student and this question was given by our mathematics teacher a year ago.
this is part of JEE EXAM syllabus ,
i tried in this way..
$$\lim_{x\to 1}{\left(\frac{(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^{2n})}{({(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^n)})^2}\right)}$$
$$ =\lim_{x\to 1}{\left(\frac{(1-x^{n+1})(1-x^{n+2})\cdots(1-x^{2n})}{{(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^n)}}\right)}$$
then knowing that 
$$\lim_{x\to 1}{(\frac{1-x^n}{1-x})}=n$$  hence

$$\lim_{x\to 1}{\left(\frac{(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^{2n})}{({(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^n)})^2}\right)}
= \binom{2n}{n}$$ 
Is this right? 
Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: It seems you have a $n$ factor more at the numerator and that you have lost a factor $n!$ at the denominator.

Comment: @gimusi yup edited the answer and tried your method too, i have some more difficult questions ,i will ask them by tomorow.

Comment: It seems you have yet an extra factor $n$ in the numerator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have that

$$(1-x^k)=(1-x)(\overbrace{1+x+\ldots x^{k-1}}^{k\,terms})$$

therefore

$$\lim_{x\to 1}{\left(\frac{(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^{2n})}{({(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^n)})^2}\right)}=$$$$=\lim_{x\to 1} {\left(\frac{(1)(1+x)\cdots(1+x+\ldots+x^{2n-1})}{({(1)(1+x)\cdots(1+x+\ldots+x^{n-1})})^2}\right)}=\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}=\binom{2n}{n}$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient

Comment: @Travis Yes of course we can also put in that way! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I assumed you were aware of that, I added the comment to provide some flavor for OP/subsequent readers who are not.